# Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/patch/.pic' and I am goin g to ignore it

Tags: tikz-pgf

I get the following error while compiling:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/patch/.pic' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I'm using tex live with update packages. I checked similar questions on SE, but the suggestions didn't worked for me. I have pgf version v3.00 and tikz. Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzset{patch/.pic = {
\draw[fill=green!30] (-1.8,3.5) to[out=10, in=190] (-1,5) to (-0.2,3.5) to [out=-140, in=45] (-1,2) to [out=145, in=-35] (-1.8,3.5) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!60] (-1,2) to [out=145, in=-35] (-1.8,3.5) -- (-1.8,3.3) -- (-1,1.5) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!30] (-0.2,3.5) to[out=-140, in=45] (-1,2) -- (-1,1.5) -- (-0.2, 3.3) -- cycle;},}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.3cm, x=1.2cm,font=\sffamily]

\pic at (0,0) {patch};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Works for me with pdfLaTeX. Could you please add `\listfiles` to your preamble and copy the part of your `.log` file, which starts with ` *File List*` to your question.

Comment: I put \listfiles at the first row. But there is no output with *File List* :(

Comment: Two friends of mine tried it also and they have the same error message. It's really weird that it works for you with pdflatex.

Comment: please open your log-file in a separate editor. The File List starts on line 365. I just updated everything again and your MWE works without error. Please delete your auxiliary files and compile from your terminal with `pdflatex yourFile.tex`.

Comment: The thing is there is no file list output. I tried it with other documents and there I have the file list output if I'm putting \listfiles at the beginning of the document. For this particular script I have for some reason no file list out put